# Using grep to find all strings (with %) in files recursively

Tags: regex, grep, escaping

To find all occurrences of `printf` in all files recursively:

```
grep -rnw ~/bin/ -e "printf"
```

However, how to escape the search pattern `printf '%0`?

I failed in the following trials to escape the percentage sign:

```
grep -rnw ~/bin/ -e "printf '%0"

grep -rnw ~/bin/ -e "printf \'\%0"

grep -rnw ~/bin/ -e "printf \'%%0"
```

Sample file:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '%04d' "$var"
```

Comment: You don't need to escape it, none of those characters have special meaning in a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks. But with `printf '%0` returns no results.

Comment: Then there aren't any matches.

Comment: The `-w` option might be causing a problem. What's after `%0` in the files?

Comment: With pattern `printf '`, there are many matches showing `printf '%0 ... `.

Comment: Please add a sample file that you expect it to match.

Comment: The recursion seems to be irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Sample added. I need the recursion too.

Comment: Of course you need the recursion, but it has nothing to do with the regexp problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you used the `-w` option, which only matches whole words. In your file, `%0` is the beginning of the word `%04d`. Since there's no word boundary after `%0`, it doesn't match.

Get rid of the `-w` option and it will match. However, it will also match

```
fprintf '%04d' "$var"
```

Since you want to match a word boundary before `printf`, use the `\b` word boundary pattern.

```
grep -rn ~/bin/ -e "\\bprintf '%0"
```